# Beautiful soup nesting loops

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My XML has nested structure similar to this:

```
<xml>
<top>
<main_record attr1="val1" attr2 = "val2" attr3="val3">
    <sub_record attrx="valx" attry="valy" />
</main_record>
<main_record attr1="val4" attr2 = "val5" attr3="val6">
    <sub_record attrx="valx2" attry="valy2" />
</main_record>
<main_record attr1="val7" attr2 = "val8" attr3="val9">
    <sub_record attrx="valx3" attry="valy3" />
</main_record>
</top>
</xml>
```

I'm trying to use beautiful soup to extract the data for each "main_record" along with its "sub_record" attributes so I can work with it in rows in a CSV file.

I can get a loop working to print out all the attr1, attr2 and attr3 values in the file, but when I try to add a sub-loop inside to get the attrx and attry, it does not work correctly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open("C:\\tracker.log", "r")
x = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser')

for entity in soup.find_all('main_record'):
    print(entity.get('attr1'))
    print(entity.get('attr2'))
    print(entity.get('attr3'))
    for positions in soup.find('sub_record'):
        print(positions.get('attrx'))
        print(positions.get('attry'))
```

Any help/pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for index,entity in enumerate(soup.find_all('main_record')):
    attr1 = entity.get('attr1')
    attr2 = entity.get('attr2')
    attr3 = entity.get('attr3')
    attrx = entity.find('sub_record').get('attrx')
    attry = entity.find('sub_record').get('attry')
    print(f'{index}) attr1 is {attr1}, attr2 is {attr2}, attr3 is {attr3}, attrx is {attrx}, attry is {attry}')
```

The output:

```
0) attr1 is val1, attr2 is val2,attr3 is val3,attrx is valx,attry is valy
1) attr1 is val4, attr2 is val5,attr3 is val6,attrx is valx2,attry is valy2
2) attr1 is val7, attr2 is val8,attr3 is val9,attrx is valx3,attry is valy3
```

Answer (score 1):

For second for loop use `entity.find_all`

check below code:

```
for entity in soup.find_all('main_record'):
    print(entity.get('attr1'))
    print(entity.get('attr2'))
    print(entity.get('attr3'))
    for positions in entity.find_all('sub_record'):
        print(positions.get('attrx'))
        print(positions.get('attry'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert to json/dictionary, then have pandas flatten it out. You'd need to `pip install xmltodict`

Given:

```
xml_file.xml = '''
<xml>
<top>
<main_record attr1="val1" attr2 = "val2" attr3="val3">
    <sub_record attrx="valx" attry="valy" />
</main_record>
<main_record attr1="val4" attr2 = "val5" attr3="val6">
    <sub_record attrx="valx2" attry="valy2" />
</main_record>
<main_record attr1="val7" attr2 = "val8" attr3="val9">
    <sub_record attrx="valx3" attry="valy3" />
</main_record>
</top>
</xml>'''
```

**Code:**

```
import xmltodict
import pandas as pd

with open("xml_file.xml") as xml_file:
    data_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_file.read())

df = pd.json_normalize(data_dict, record_path=['xml','top', 'main_record'])
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
  @attr1 @attr2 @attr3 sub_record.@attrx sub_record.@attry
0   val1   val2   val3              valx              valy
1   val4   val5   val6             valx2             valy2
2   val7   val8   val9             valx3             valy3
```

And if you want to get rid of the `'@'`, just replace those with `''`:

```
df.columns = [x.replace('@','') for x in df.columns]

print(df)
  attr1 attr2 attr3 sub_record.attrx sub_record.attry
0  val1  val2  val3             valx             valy
1  val4  val5  val6            valx2            valy2
2  val7  val8  val9            valx3            valy3
```